# BreezeJs loading metadata 5 times on the page, trying to use fetchMetaData but it errors

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am trying to get the metadata before I perform any queries on the page, because each query is trying to get the metadata for a total of 5 times and the page is very slow. I am hoping this helps.

//version info:
var breeze = {
        version: "1.5.4",
        metadataVersion: "1.0.5"
    };

Howevever I am getting this error:

**manager.fetchMetadata(...).then(...).fail is not a function**

Here is the code sample:

```
var manager = emProvider.createManager();

function getMetaData()
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    manager.fetchMetadata()
          .then(function (data, status) {

              deferred.resolve(data);
              console.log('manager.fetchMetadata() success');
          })
          .fail(function (data, status) {

              deferred.reject(data);
              console.log('manager.fetchMetadata() reject');
          });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

THis is what the createManager function looks like from the injected 'emProvider' service.

```
  var masterManager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceRoot + 'odata/');

   // private function to create a new manager
    function createManager() {
        var manager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy(); // same configuration; no    entities in cache.
        // ... copy in some entities (e.g.,picklists) from masterManager
        return manager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following... surround all of your code blocks with anonymous self-invoking functions except for the master manager creation, comment out the getMetaData function, be sure to pick up the right adapter for your service... [breeze odata configuration](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/server-odata) , make sure Q is on your js bundle at the top of your page.

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "odata");
var masterManager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceRoot + 'odata/');

(function () {
    var op = breeze.FilterQueryOp;
    var query = null;
    query = new breeze.EntityQuery()...
    ...all of your other breeze code...
    masterManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$q` from AngularJS, you should use `.catch` instead of `.fail`.  [AngularJS uses .catch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for errors in promises.